# Why does z-index not affect parent silblings?

Tags: html, css, z-index

Please take a look at this markup:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner" />
</div>
<div class="outer" style="background-color: green">
<div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;

    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

which is rendered as this:

[image: result]

([You can also take a look at jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KVYM7/)).

Why is the green div overlapping the red, although its z-index is lower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red box participates in the blue box's stacking context, not the green one's. The z-index of the green box is irrelevant to the stack level of the red box.

Since the green and blue boxes are both `.outer` and have the same z-index of 10, and the green comes after the blue in the source, the green is positioned above the blue *and* its contents.

Comment: That's definitely an answer, thank you. But can you also tell me how to manage that both green and blue share their "stacking context"?

Comment: @Mulmoth: They're already participating in the same stacking context - the default one.

Comment: But if they do, why is green not recognizing the z-index of red? How can I let red overlap green then?

Comment: Because red is participating in blue's stacking context. Unfortunately the only way I can think of is to make green's z-index lower than blue's.

Comment: Ok, that's certainly something. Thank you!